# Overfitting decreases over time

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, deep-learning, validation

During my training I have got the following results after 10th epoch:

1. training accuracy amounts to 97% and is stable;
2. training loss is decreasing from 0.2530 and is decreasing 0.02-0.05 per epoch,
3. validation accuracy is increasing from 84% and is increasing 1-2%
   per epoch,
4. validation loss is decreasing, from 0.67 and is decreasing (0.2-0.5 per epoch).

The question is whether I should stop my training. Is there any risk that my model will learn the validation dataset without explicitly training on it?

Comment: Your model cannot learn the validation data set without explicitly training on it *unless* you use *your knowledge* of the validation performance to tune many, many parameters in the model.  If you're just trying to figure out where to stop the training, you simply want to minimize the validation loss.